# Run Clear() method on BindingList<Object> causes "Cross Thread" Exception

Tags: c#, datagridview, invoke, bindinglist

I am using `Bindinglist<Object>` and DataGridView to fill list of objects and display it in a DataGridView.

My list is filled by another thread than the DataGridView thread, so I am using `Invoke` method in the `ListChanged()` method that I wrote in the GUI thread (the thread that the DataGridView on it).

Now, as long as I add Object to the BindingList in the main thread (that treat the list) - the DataGridView was updated Ok, BUT, When I try to run the `Clear()` method on the BindingList - my  `ListChanged()` method run, but, I still get the Exception: `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dgv' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on`. Why am I getting this exception? I treat the GUI already in the `ListChanged()` method, No?

**Code:**

```
myBindingList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(Events_ListChanged);
BindingSource source = new BindingSource(myBindingList, null);
dgv.DataSource = source;
```

Run the `Clear()` method in the main thread:

```
myBindingList.Clear();
```

my `ListChanged()` method:

```
void Events_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (dgv.InvokeRequired)
     {
         dgv.Invoke(new UpdateDataGridItemDelegate(this.Events_ListChanged), sender, e);
         return;
     }
     else
     {
         source.ResetBindings(false);
         lblTotal.Text = myBindingList.Count.ToString();
     }
}
```

And I emphasize: when I add Objects to the binding list, it works good and I don't get an exception (I am doing it from the same thread that I run the `Clear()` method), but when I run the Clear() method it throw me "Cross Thread" exception. Any Idea Why?

Comment: "Control 'dgv' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" I don't see anything called `dgv` in any code that you provided. Is this the **actual** code or an approximation?

Comment: It is an entirely valid exception.  Your Clear() call is made from a worker thread, so the binding is updated on the worker thread, so the control is updated on the worker thread.  That's illegal and would make your program fail in impossible to diagnose ways.

Comment: That's what I said: I update the GUI from the GUI thread by `Invoke()` method

Comment: spender, I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my `ListChanged()` method as the following and it works!:

```
void Events_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (dgv.InvokeRequired)
     {
         dgv.Invoke(new UpdateDataGridItemDelegate(this.Events_ListChanged), sender, e);
         return;
     }
     else
     {
         if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset)
         {
             dgv.DataSource = null;
             source = new BindingSource(myBindingList, null);
             dgv.DataSource = source;
         }
         else
             source.ResetBindings(false);
         lblTotal.Text = myBindingList.Count.ToString();
     }
}
```

I unbound the data source of the DataGridView and bound it again to the BindingList in case of reset BindingList.

Comment: What does your delegate look like? I have exactly the same issue as you did. Trying to Add/Clear items into a BindingList that's bound to my DataGridView source from another thread.